# How do I align these buttons?

Tags: html, css

```css
a.cr-button {
    border: solid blue;
}

.job-entry a {
    height: 65px;
    margin: 5px;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="btn-group-vertical col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8 col-xs-12" style="display:table;">
            <div class="job-entry row large-text" style="display:table-row;">
                <div style="display:table-cell;width:75px;">
                    <a class="btn cr-button pad">
                        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/64x64/000/fff" width="50">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div style="display:table-cell">
                    <a class="btn cr-button pad-lg" href="#">Test Job 1</a>
                </div>
                <div style="display:table-cell;width:75px;">
                    <a href="/Builder/DeleteJob" class="btn cr-button pad">
                        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/64x64/000/fff" width="50">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

So how do I line these three anchors? I've tried `vertical-align` in every tag that makes sense with every value that makes sense.

[JsFiddle version](http://jsfiddle.net/ujvqd2u7/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give your `div` elements a `vertical-align` set to `top`, not the `a` elements contained within them:

```
<div style="vertical-align:top; display:table-cell">
    <a class="btn cr-button pad-lg" href="#">Test Job 1</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I remembered that vertical-align had to be in the container rather than elements. I guess that was wrong. This does make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

Do like this

```css
.cr-button {
    border: solid blue;
}

.job-entry a {
    height: 65px;
    margin: 5px;
    display: block;
}
.block{vertical-align: top;}
```

```html
 <div class="btn-group-vertical col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8 col-xs-12" style="display:table;">
            <div class="job-entry row large-text" style="display:table-row;">
                <div class="block" style="display:table-cell;width:75px;">
                    <a class="btn cr-button pad">
                        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/64x64/000/fff" width="50">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="block" style="display:table-cell">
                    <a class="btn cr-button pad-lg" href="#">Test Job 1</a>
                </div>
                <div class="block" style="display:table-cell;width:75px;">
                    <a href="/Builder/DeleteJob" class="btn cr-button pad">
                        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/64x64/000/fff" width="50">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: +1 This is basically what James Donnelly has above. I do like the way you organized the CSS a lot more, but he had his answer first.

Comment: Sure, doesn't matter. You had use inline styling you can set common properties on .block